# MediaPlayerState.play() undefined in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to play video on IOS using react native. I am trying to use the [MediaPlayerState](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/mediaplayerstate.html) to have control over the video playback.

The MediaPlayerState constructor returns defined object, however, the play() does not work as it is undefined.

```
import MediaPlayerState from 'react-native-video';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  playerState: new MediaPlayerState({autoPlay: false, muted: true}) // init with muted, autoPlay
 };
```

this.state.playerState is defined always, of course.
But this.state.playerState.play() is undefined. Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly you are using `this.state.playerState.play()`? Its not easy to help with this less of code.

Comment: I am using .play() in the same component. Can you kindly explain where this can be used? I believe it can be called anywhere in the component.

Comment: it can be used anywhere in the component but it has to access to `this` so I'm kindly asking you to add more code to your question.